# canon MG4250 and two sided printing

Tags: printing

I have Ubuntu 14.04 and canon MG4250 printer.
Everything works but two sided printing doesn't work like it should.
When start printing in two sided mode it starts printing right at the top of the page. So two sided printing isn't usable. My wife really need it for school. So now I must run windows just for printing.
I tried every possible setup, but it's allways the same. One side normal and other sperts printing at the top.

Is there some problem with drivers? Bug in drivers?
Is someone using same printer in Ubuntu and can test if have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have an MG4250 and both Ubuntu 12.04 and 16.04 (but not 14.04).  Canon advertise the (latest) driver as for 12.04 on their website.  It works fine in 12.04 but as described above in 16.04 (as well as colours being far too dark).

Note: This is after installing the third party driver referenced at [Canon Printer Driver & ScanGear MP For Ubuntu 14.04](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/12/canon-driver-scangear-mp-ubuntu-14-04/) which presumably is expected to work for 14.04.

Workaround?  Install 12.04 on a separate partition and print from that rather than from Windows.  The 12.04 can see the other partition so you can get at your files without duplication.  Inconvenient but it works.

There may be other ways forward.

Comment: I think you could install 12.04 in a virtual machine instead of installing it on a separate partition.

Answer (score 0):

We had the exact same problem on Linux Mint 18.3 recently (two-sided printing not aligned properly on one side). The solution was to install the official driver from Canon, available here:

[https://www.canon.co.uk/support/consumer_products/products/fax__multifunctionals/inkjet/pixma_mg_series/pixma_mg4250.aspx?type=drivers&driverdetailid=tcm:14-994525&os=Linux (64-bit)&language=](https://www.canon.co.uk/support/consumer_products/products/fax__multifunctionals/inkjet/pixma_mg_series/pixma_mg4250.aspx?type=drivers&driverdetailid=tcm:14-994525&os=Linux%20(64-bit)&language=)

Choose the "MG4200 series IJ Printer Driver Ver. 3.80 for Linux (debian Packagearchive)".

Unpack the file and run the `install.sh` script. You may need to install the `libtiff4` package, if the install script complains about it. You can find this here: https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/libtiff4

Hope this helps someone!